# Should I increase the tempfile limit size?

Tags: postgresql

I've been struggling with this question for a while now.

Been working with a big database in a postgres which periodically has its data extracted to column-based datasources in Tableau. The problem starts when the extraction processes (copying data to Tableau) goes over its edge to request more than 50GB of data in one query. So we break the query into many materialized views and union them later. But this grows fast and eventually the same problem again, but now for many materialized views.

I haven't been able to find any article, suggestion, hint, whispers online about increasing the temp-file limit size. Although my guts tells me this is wrong, I think Im not able to comprehend fully all the bad points of increasing it.

So go on, roast me for considering such a filthy thing. But tell me why you think its a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default setting of temp_file_limit is -1, meaning unlimited.

Did whoever in your organization changed it away from the default not document why they did so?  I don't think you need a great deal of justification to restore a default if no one knows why it was changed in the first place.

Comment: Thanks mate, a bit of misunderstanding but its really appreciated you took the time to reply a rookie fellow